# How do you do a distinct query with a criteria to find a specific substring in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am a beginner at Kusto and am trying to create a query that returns a distinct (`fruit`) column based on another (`data`) column containing a specific substring.

In the example below, if an "`awesome`" substring is found in the `data` column then return `"found"` that and if not, return `"not found"` but always maintain the distinctness of the first column.

```
let Fruit = datatable(fruit:string, data:string) 
[
    "apple", "awesome",
    "apple", "beast",
    "banana", "a beast",
    "orange", "awesome cat",
    "orange", "blah" 
];
```

So the desired output would be:

```
"apple", "found",
"banana", "not found",
"orange", "found",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one option would be using the `countif()` aggregation function, with `fruit` as the aggregation key, as follows:

```
datatable(fruit:string, data:string) 
[
    "apple", "awesome",
    "apple", "beast",
    "banana", "a beast",
    "orange", "awesome cat",
    "orange", "blah" 
]
| summarize countif(data has 'awesome') by fruit
| project fruit, output = iff(countif_ == 0, "not found", "found")
```

| fruit | output |
| --- | --- |
| apple | found |
| banana | not found |
| orange | found |