# KQL Serialise value from Union table set

Tags: azure, kql

We have a query in which we are triing to make Time to Time comparison during 24 hours time span.

The query looks like this:

```
let start_time1=startofday(now() - 48h);
let start_time=startofday(now() - 24h);
let end_time=now();
let end_time1 = startofday(now()-24h);
let TableA = Source
| where TimeGenerated > start_time1 and TimeGenerated < end_time1
| where Computer == "ComputerName"
| where CounterName == "% Free Space"
| where InstanceName == "E:"
| summarize x= arg_min(format_datetime(TimeGenerated,'HH:mm:ss'), CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), InstanceName
| order by format_datetime(TimeGenerated,'HH:mm:ss') desc;
let TableB = Source
| where TimeGenerated > start_time and TimeGenerated < end_time
| where Computer == "ComputerName"
| where CounterName == "% Free Space"
| where InstanceName == "E:"
| summarize x= arg_min(format_datetime(TimeGenerated,'HH:mm:ss'), CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), InstanceName
| order by format_datetime(TimeGenerated,'HH:mm:ss') desc;
TableA
| union kind=inner TableB
| serialize | extend prevValue = prev(CounterValue, 1)
| extend diffvalue = CounterValue - prevValue
| extend trend = case(CounterValue < prevValue, "Free Space Reduces",
CounterValue > prevValue, "Free Space Increases",
"No difference")
| order by format_datetime(TimeGenerated,'HH:mm:ss') desc;
```

The query returns correct values, correctly ordered in pairs (e.g. 20/09/2021 10:00:00; 21/09/2021 10:00:00; 20/09/2021 11:00:00; 21/09/2021 11:00:00)
However, the previous row seems to work with the values based on the original queries (eg. rownum-1 for 21/09/2021 11:00:00 is 21/09/2021 10:00:00 instead of 20/09/2021 11:00:00)

I know, that serialise "fixes" the row order, but i do not know how to fix it as for the result of the union operation.

Comment: it would greatly help if you provide a small sample dataset input (using the datatable operator) and then the expected output of the query for that dataset. see this question as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230807/how-do-you-do-a-distinct-query-with-a-criteria-to-find-a-specific-substring-in-k

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.